# Oracle: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ERROR

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my query. I am not sure what cause the Not A group by expression error. Any help is much appreciated. =)

```
SELECT c.courseID, c.courseName, AVG(a.Mark) as Average_Mark
FROM course c, assessment a
WHERE c.courseID = a.courseID
Group by c.courseID, c.courseName
ORDER BY Mark DESC;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT c.courseid,
       c.coursename,
       AVG(a.mark) AS Average_Mark
FROM   COURSE c
       INNER JOIN ASSESSMENT a
               ON c.courseid = a.courseid
GROUP  BY c.courseid,
          c.coursename
ORDER  BY 3 DESC; -- or ORDER BY Average_Mark DESC
```

As you aggregate several values of `Mark` in order to compute the average, it becomes impossible to sort on each value of `Mark`. You have to sort on the result of the computation, i.e. `Average_Mark`.

---

From a more general point of view, you are allowed to `ORDER BY` a non `SELECT`ed column only if this column is part of the queried tables and if you don't use any `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` (unless you `GROUP BY` this non displayed column, then you can `ORDER BY` it).

The reason is simple: If you use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT`, several rows will be potentially displayed as one. Non displayed values in those "merged" rows can potentially be different from each other, making any `ORDER BY` impossible on those values.

Some DBMS (MySQL at least) behave differently, allowing `ORDER`ing `BY` non displayed values, even with `GROUP BY`. But MySQL seems then to order by the first encountered value of non displayed value (see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2b20/3)). So, better keep in mind that this should be avoided, to prevent unpredictible results.

**EDIT:** See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) about MySQL `GROUP BY` handling.

Comment: And why does it report that error as "not A GROUP BY expression"? Also, I'm currently getting this error in a queue without any order by.

Comment: @masterxilo Ask another question describing your specific problem, the DBMS you're using, and the code your trying to execute.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ORDER BY Average_Mark
```

instead of

```
ORDER BY Mark
```