# Why "not a GROUP BY expression"?

Tags: sql

I have some problems with understanding the "not a GROUP BY expression" error.
As you can see bellow, I have 2 tables: students and grade_students. I need to create a select that will print: students.name, students.year, students.code and the avg of his grades (grade_students.grade).

If I create the SELECT to print me only name and avg is just fine:

```
SELECT 
    students.name, avg(grade_students.grade) 
FROM 
    students
INNER JOIN 
    grade_students ON students.code = grade_students.code
GROUP BY 
    students.name 
ORDER BY 
    avg_gr;
```

BUT when I ask for year and code as bellow I got the "not a GROUP BY expression"

```
SELECT 
    students.name, avg(grade_students.grade) AS avg_gr, 
    students.year, students.code 
FROM 
    students
INNER JOIN 
    grade_students ON students.code= grade_students.code
GROUP BY 
    students.name 
ORDER BY 
    avg_gr;
```

Please give me a hint to figure out what is wrong here.

PS. I'm not doing my homework on stackoverflow.com but I admit, I'm preparing myself for an exam :)

EDIT:

```
Name    Null     Type      -- students    
------- -------- ------------ 
CODE NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
NAME VARCHAR2(20) 
SECOND_NAME VARCHAR2(20) 
YEAR NUMBER(1)  

Name Null Type          -- grade_students
---- ---- ----------- 
CODE NUMBER(4) REFERENCES students ( code),   
NOTA      NUMBER(5,2)
```

Comment: Providing fiddle examples in your question will increase the chances to solve the problem

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? I think that's an Oracle error message.

Comment: The columns that you select in group by queries must either be the columns that the rows are grouped by, or aggregate functions of the columns.  Otherwise it is unclear which value to return, and the database will either behave non-deterministic, or give an error message.

Comment: OK, you removed the `mysql` tag. Why don't you add the tag for the correct database? We can help you best if you provide correct details.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to add `students.year` and `students.code` to group by clause:

```
SELECT students.name, avg(grade_students.grade) AS avg_gr, students.year, students.code FROM students
 INNER JOIN grade_students ON students.code= grade_studenti.code
 GROUP BY students.name, students.year, students.code
 ORDER BY avg_gr;
```

Or you need to aggregate those fields:

```
SELECT students.name, avg(grade_students.grade) AS avg_gr, MAX(students.year) AS max_std_year, MAX(students.code) AS max_std_code FROM students
 INNER JOIN grade_students ON students.code= grade_studenti.code
 GROUP BY students.name ORDER BY avg_gr;
```

Comment: I don't quite get this as well as in how does it solve the problem with just adding two more fields (students.year and students.code)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both of them are working! I don't really get why because I tried first just before asking on stackoverflow, but anyway I'm glad that I figure out what is with "not a GROUP BY expression".

Comment: @EricT the two added fields were the problem in original question, after adding them the query stopped working

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.name, avg(g.grade) AS avg_gr, s.year, s.code FROM students s INNER JOIN grade_students g ON s.code= g.code GROUP BY s.name, s.year, s.code ORDER BY avg_gr;
```

This problem is discussed here: [Oracle: NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746590/oracle-not-a-group-by-expression-error)

Comment: This is almost certainly just a copying error, since it would cause a very different error than the one he's getting.

Comment: No, in my code is just fine. Here I translated it in english to be easier for you to understand what I have there.

Comment: Hmm. Can you try this to see if you get the result you want? _SELECT s.name, avg(g.grade) AS avg_gr, s.year, s.code FROM students s
 INNER JOIN grade_students g ON s.code= g.code
 GROUP BY s.name, s.year, s.code
 ORDER BY avg_gr;_
It is an issue discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746590/oracle-not-a-group-by-expression-error
Seems it happens because you aggregate several values

Comment: Nimle, yup, that is one of the correct ways to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What if two students have the same name, but different years? You say you want to group by student name, so you only want to return a single record, but you also want the two years, when your result row only has room for one year.

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to use `GROUP BY` at the top level, here. You want the average student grade (per student code)? Then group *just* for that.

```
SELECT students.name, avg_grade_students.avg_grade
FROM students
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT code, AVG(grade) AS avg_grade
    FROM grade_students
    GROUP BY code
) AS avg_grade_students
ON students.code = avg_grade_students.code
ORDER BY avg_grade_students.avg_grade;
```

Here, you can add any column from `students` you want without any problems.

(Precise syntax depends slightly on the database used.)